# Group by with subsets of category columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have, as shown in my simplified example below, a data frame with two category columns and one value column. Both category columns can take values of “A”, “B”, or “C”. I want to aggregate value column over those categories, BUT I also want to consider a case where category column 1 is either “A” or “B”. In other words I want to iterate not only over all passible values of category columns, but also over a given set of combinations of those values.
The best I could come up with is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat1':['A','A','B','B','C','C'],
              'cat2':['A','B','A','B','A','B'],
              'x':[1,3,1,3,1,3]})
res1 = df.groupby(['cat1','cat2']).sum()
res2 = df.loc[(df['cat1'] == 'A') | (df['cat1'] == 'B'),['cat2','x']].groupby('cat2').sum()
res2['cat1'] = 'AB'
res2 = res2.reset_index().set_index(['cat1','cat2'])
res = res1.append(res2)
res
                x
cat1    cat2    
A         A     1
          B     3
B         A     1
          B     3
C         A     1
          B     3
AB        A     2
          B     6
```

It works fine, but as my actual task involves much more than just two categories with three possible values this approach gets messy. Is there are more elegant or more efficient way of doing this?

In respond to comments, here is sample data and logic behind it.
Say, I’m studying gym going habits of a group of college students.  Sample data is this:

```
    VisitTime   Collage mode of commute     TimeAtJym
0   noon-17:00  a&s     bus                 30
1   noon-17:00  a&s     car, then bus       45
2   noon-17:00  a&s     car (only)          90
3   17:00-22:00 a&s     bus                 40
4   17:00-22:00 a&s     car, then bus       50
5   17:00-22:00 a&s     car (only)          35
6   7:00-noon   a&s     bus                 55
7   7:00-noon   a&s     car, then bus       70
8   7:00-noon   a&s     car (only)          40
9   noon-17:00  law     bus                 45
10  noon-17:00  law     car, then bus       40
11  noon-17:00  law     car (only)           4
12  17:00-22:00 law     bus                 90
13  17:00-22:00 law     car, then bus       120
14  17:00-22:00 law     car (only)          30
15  7:00-noon   law     bus                 25
16  7:00-noon   law     car, then bus       90
17  7:00-noon   law     car (only)          80
```

I want to know the average time spent at the recreation by time of day and by mode of transport, so I do this:

```
res1 = sss.groupby(['VisitTime','mode of commute']).mean()
res1

                               TimeAtJym
VisitTime       mode of commute     
17:00-22:00     bus             65.0
                car (only)      32.5
                car, then bus   85.0
7:00-noon       bus             40.0
                car (only)      60.0
                car, then bus   80.0
noon-17:00      bus             37.5
                car (only)      47.0
                car, then bus   42.5
```

I also want to know the avarage time for *non-evening* students, so I do this:

```
res2 = sss.loc[(sss['VisitTime'] == '7:00-noon') | (sss['VisitTime'] == 'noon-17:00')].groupby(['mode of commute']).mean()
res2['VisitTime'] = 'not evening'
res2 = res2.reset_index().set_index(['VisitTime','mode of commute'])
res2

                            TimeAtJym
VisitTime   mode of commute     
not evening bus             38.75
            car (only)      53.50
            car, then bus   61.25
```

If I were to consider non-evening students who took the bus ( that’s *bus only* and *car, then bus*), then I’ll need a slightly longer expression, and in my actual study, because number of subcategories is larger, the approach that I’ve taken gets messy. For same reason, using `!=` instead of `== | ==` won’t help. I hope this clarifies my question

Comment: Can you show your sample data ?

Comment: It would make a little more sense if you could show your actual data, expected output and the logic behind _that_.

Comment: I’ve added something close to actual data, hope you can follow my logic